# PSU using -15V and +15V in order to get 30V?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, circuit-analysis, audio

I've been a couple of days looking for an answer, but without much success. I was wondering if I can connect a 30V audio device to the +15V and -15V of a PSU (+15V / GND / -15V)? Or is it preferred to have a PSU (+30V / GND / -30V) and only using +30V and GND? I've read online that I should use the second option but couldn't find why this is better.

The audio device in question is a TSA8498 rated for 14V to 39V.
The PSU is a switching power supply with +15 / GND / -15V (10A).
I want to run it on ~30V.

Comment: It depends entirely on what this "audio device" is.

Comment: And it depends entirely on also what this "power supply" is.

Comment: Yes if both are identical , adequate and floating, otherwise not. Superposition applies if effectively linear voltage sources.

Comment: Does the audio device only need +30V and GND (might be stated as 30V/0V)? A lot of audio circuits require split supplies, i.e. +15/0/-15V, or +30/0/-30V. But a whole device might have its own power circuitry that can for example turn a single-ended (i.e. 30V/0V) supply into split supplies (e.g. +15/0/-15V).

Comment: The audio device in question is a TSA8498 rated for 14V to 39V. The PSU is a switching power supply with +15 / GND / -15V (10A).

Comment: Should work, although depending on the specific supply this may or may not be a bad idea. In particular, if the supply does not have floating outputs then you would be restricted to bluetooth for input and would blow up anything hooked to RCA. Also some advice: when people say that it depends on the choice of supply, you should say what supply you are using.